# header changing style when uploaded to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a website which is live. Its header should be like the below image:

[image]

When I am working on local its like that only, but when I am uploading to the server the header becomes small in every page except one page

[image]

every page it becomes small [page](https://%20competebig.com/ayusch) except this page [except](https://competebig.com/ayusch/aboutus.php)

The CSS is below for header:

```
body {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-form {
  border-color: transparent;
  padding: 10px 22px 0 5px;
}

.navbar-inverse :hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-header {
  float: none;
}

.custom-navbar {
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: #01b7a8;
  border-color: #01b7a8;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 10px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
  font-size: 19px;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
  background-color: #01b7a8;
  color: #0a2240;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:focus,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .custom-navbar {
    display: inline-flex;
  }
  .custom-navbar li .btn {
    margin-bottom: 2vh;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-right {
    /*position: relative;
                top: -7vh*/
  }
  .custom-navbar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1vh;
    z-index: 2222;
    right: 3vh;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a {
  color: #0a2240;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a {
  color: #0a2240;
  background-color: #fff;
  /* padding: 0 15px 0 15px; */
}

.dropdown-menu>li>a {
  color: #0a2240 !important;
  background-color: #efeff0;
}


/* dropdown-menu */

@media (max-width: 767px) .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a {
  line-height: 20px;
}

.container-fluid {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #d9f4f2;
}

.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -6px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
  border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 132%;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 0 0;
  border: 0px;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  float: right;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  border-left-color: #333! important;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-menu>li>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: #0a2240 !important;
  background-color: #efeff0;
}

.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover {
  background-color: #d9f4f2;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  float: right;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  border-left-color: #ccc;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
  border-left-color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
  float: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
  left: -100%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
  border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}


/*dropdown-menu end */


/*top button */

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #2B3856 !important;
  color: #f8dd4d !important;
  border-color: #2B3856 !important;
}

.btn:active {
  background-color: #2B3856 !important;
  color: #f8dd4d !important;
  border-color: #2B3856 !important;
}


/*links styling*/

#myNavbara>li>a: hover {
  background-color: #01b7a8 !important;
  color: #0a2240 !important;
}
```

can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, there is must be a live CDN link and which does not work on local may be because internet issue and when you upload on server then It works with internet.

You can check your all the files for this. May be this will work for you.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm noticing that you have inline styles applied to your header buttons, which are different for [this](https://competebig.com/ayusch/aboutus.php) page and [this](https://competebig.com/ayusch/contactus.php) page. Also, I noticed that some of your font sizes are in `vh`. Try using something like `em` or `rem` instead.

I don't know how you're building this website, but if possible, drop the inline styles and style the buttons with their class instead.